# pubnub webhook for a specific channel?

Tags: pubnub

I need to know the user presence when he will join only his inbound channel. as I need to take some action in my project when the action of user is `join` and channel is `inbound`.

is there any way from which my REST endpoint called when only same events occur?

Comment: We are tracking this in the support ticket you filed. Please see our response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PubNub Presence Web Hooks apply to all channels and cannot be configured to apply to just some channels. So you will receive `join` events on all channels.